# haskell branchz int,jump int and mark int stack

Tags: haskell, stack, branch

```
--my datatypes
data Command =PushK Int | Mark Int | Jump Int | Branchz Int deriving (Eq,Show)
type Program = [Command]
type Stack = [Int]

interpret::Program -> Stack 
interpret = interpret [] where
    interpret stack []                      = stack
    interpret stack ( PushK n:xs)           =interpret (n:stack)xs
    interpret stack (Mark n:xs)             =interpret stack xs

Interpret(Branchz n:xs) (a:b)  =if(0 ==a) then interpret (dropWhile (n /= )Program) b  program else interpret xs b program

Interpret (Jump n :xs) stack = Interpret(dropWhile(n/=)program) stack program
```

I need now interpret Branchz Int and Jump Int, but I don't know how to get the program code in the second part.

Comment: You need to keep a copy of your program, so that you may use it to "rewind" to its start and search for the `Mark` it is supposed to `Jump` or `Branch` to.

Comment: ok thx,but how can i make the copy?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was close:

```
data Command = PushK Int | Mark Int | Jump Int | Branchz Int deriving (Eq,Show)
type Program = [Command]
type Stack = [Int]

interpret :: Program -> Stack 
interpret program = interpret_ [] program
  where
    interpret_ stack []             = stack
    interpret_ stack (PushK n:xs)   = interpret_ (n:stack) xs
    interpret_ stack (Mark n:xs)    = interpret_ stack xs
    interpret_ (a:b) (Branchz n:xs) = 
      if (0 == a) then 
        interpret_ b (skip (n/=) program)
      else 
        interpret_ b xs
    interpret_ stack (Jump n:xs)    = interpret_ stack (skip (n/=) program)
    skip f (Mark a:b) = if not (f a) then b else skip f b
    skip f (_:b)      = skip f b
```

In your definition of `interpret`, you didn't specify the name of the parameter (the `Program` to be interpreted), which is necessary to be able to refer to it when "rewinding", ie. recursively call the interpreter at a position sought by `dropWhile`, which I replaced by `skip` here.

Comment: `dropWhile (n/=) program` looks wrong since `program` is not a list of `Int`

Comment: @chi yes, I had my own implementation of `dropWhile`, and then discovered that the function actually exists, so I dropped my own, but I forgot to update the check condition. I reinstated my version, renamed it `skip`. I guess I could have replaced `(n/=)` with `(Mark n/=)`.